# How To Clone Entire HD With Multiple OSes to SSD

Tags: partitioning, ssd, clone

After searching & reading through many answers & online results, Im posting my particular question below.

I have a 250GB Hard Drive which has two OSes (Win10 & Ubuntu) & a storage partition. I just bought a 512GB SSD & a SSD to USB cable.

How can I clone all the partitions (Windows 10, Ubuntu & storage partition) to SSD drive & have the spare space created as a separate partition.

I would ideally like to do this in Ubuntu (my primary OS).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're going from a smaller disk drive, to a larger disk drive, I can safely say that `Clonezilla` is the tool of choice. Download a Ubuntu-based copy from http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=alternative and burn it to a CD/DVD/USB, and boot to it.

Their main page at http://clonezilla.org can give you more details about the program.

When you're done, 1/2 of the new disk will be unallocated space, and you can create whatever partition(s) you'd like.

When you're done, use `sudo fdisk -l`, or `sudo parted /dev/sda` and use the `align-check` command, to assure that your partitions are properly aligned, or you'll suffer performance issues. For more information on these commands, type `man fdisk` or `man parted`.

Comment: Agree that this is a the utility I would (and have) used for this purpose.

Comment: Im going through this right now... would you please elaborate on the `fdisk -l` & `parted align-check` commands please. I am getting `permission denied` error.

Comment: I'm sorry, my error, the commands should start with `sudo` ie: `sudo fdisk -l`. In terminal, type `man parted` to learn more about how to use the `align-check` option in `parted`.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't figure out the align-check bit, however, the system is working for now. Would appreciate more insight if possible on it. Thanks

Comment: `sudo parted /dev/sda`, `print`, `align-check optimal 1`, `align-check optimal 2`, etc., `quit`.

Comment: thanks @heynnema. Its working now! My first SSD drive experience.

Comment: Good job! Did you do the parted thingie? Are you aligned?